# join two data tables based on column conditions

Tags: r, data.table

I was wondering how joining of two data.tables based on column conditions works! So which column is used, inner or/before outer?

```
require(data.table)

outer <- data.table(KeyColumn=letters, value_outer=seq_along(letters))
inner  <- data.table(KeyColumn=letters[4:6], value_inner=c(100,101,102))

setkey(outer, KeyColumn)
setkey(inner, KeyColumn)

outer[inner] # works as expected

inner[value_outer<10] # error as expected, because column doesn't exist in inner

outer[inner[value_outer<10], NewColumn := value_inner] # why does this work?
```

If the conditional column is present (names identical) in both data.tables, but values differ, which column is used, inner or/before outer?

Comment: if `value_outer` column exists in `inner`, that's what will be used, otherwise what you wrote is equivalent to `outer[inner[outer[, value_outer < 10]], NewColumn := value_inner]` and you can now look at each component and understand what's going on

Comment: @eddi where `inner[outer[, value_outer < 10]]` came from?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I just rewrote OP's expression in an equivalent way (i.e. both what I have and what OP wrote do the exact same thing if `inner` doesn't have that column), that has the advantage that you can look at each piece individually to understand why OP's expression seems to work (and OP's expression only works accidentally)

Comment: @eddi, I understand that your code is equivalent, but I don't understand why OPs code works, i.e., what happens under the hood? Your line or something else?

Comment: `inner` looks at its columns, doesn't find `value_outer`, so looks at its parent environment, which is `outer`, thus that `value_outer` is same as `outer$value_outer`

Comment: @eddi, that looks reasonable, I would consider posting this as an answer

Comment: @DavidArenburg too much work - feel free to do so yourself :)

Comment: @eddi many thanks for your quick reply! That's what I expected, but I couldn't find a documentation for it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @eddi who answered in a comment:

`inner` looks at its columns, doesn't find `value_outer`, so looks at its parent environment, which is `outer`, thus that `value_outer` is same as `outer$value_outer`